# Why are people being trapped, collected and stored in phone boxes in La Cabina?

Tags: movie, la-cabina

In La Cabina (1972), a nameless company is collecting people in phone boxes and storing them in an underground warehouse until they die. Why are they doing this?

Comment: I don't think there's any explanation. It's whimsical, like a Twilight Zone episode.

Comment: It is a metaphor for repressed homosexual urges.

Comment: @JohnO Was that a Freudian slip?

Comment: Thanks for this movie. I hadn't seen it yet. But don't you think the text of the question might be just a teensy bit spoilerish?

Comment: Well, it's 40 years old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This film can be interpreted in a variety of ways, so it depends on what you make of it.
The film can and has been interpreted as but not limited to:

1. the isolation of the individual in modern times
2. Modernity as a Procrustian Bed (an arbitrary standard rigidly adhered to)
3. an allegory for wasting away in a (glass) cubicle
4. an indictment against inhumane, faceless and indifferent corporations (or large entities)
5. The inevitability of death

I'm sure there are many other ways... but the main goal might just be to get you thinking

Comment: I thought it might be about fatherhood, because of the boy's ball.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a Movie, its a short film. And I think is more about the atmosphere that surrounds everything, being trapped in something ordinary like a phone box, and then the escalating until you realize your destiny... I know out universe answers sucks.

Comment: I'm not sure how the first line helps to answer the question. A short film is still a film.

Answer (score 2):

I had it explained to me once that the mountain cave they are taken to is a metaphor for the place Franco made people 'disappear' during his rule, so I guess it could be a statement on Franco-era Spain.

Eitherway it's a really creepy piece that has stood the test of time well.

Comment: You should expand on your answer, and provide supporting evidence. Otherwise it should be left as a comment.

Comment: @Moogle: it's no less detailed or supported than the other two answers...

Answer (score 2):

Many years since I saw this, on TV, but as I remember, there was no suggestion that the purpose of the phone boxes was to trap people.  It seemed that they were just poorly designed, so sometimes the door stuck and couldn't be opened... The emergency services spent a lot of time and effort trying to break the booth open, and couldn't... so they just took it away and put it with all the others.  The suggestion that it's an allegory of Spanish society, during and after the Franco regime, is fascinating, but the film stands on its own as a nightmarish horror story.  I only saw it once, and I've never forgotten it.